# UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification is not being fired properly

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm using iPhone5 and iOS7. I want to track the brightness of the device for that I'm using "UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification". Some times it is being fired properly and sometimes not. Is that problem of my device or iOS7 or my method?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(brightnessChanged) name:UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)brightnessChanged
{
     NSLog(@"brightness is %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);
}
```

Comment: When exactly is it not firing correctly? Is it, perhaps, when the app is in the background?

Comment: @LeoNatan When I hide the Ambient Light sensor with my hand. Some times it does but some times doesn't and I also noticed that the screen brightness is also not changing. Note : I have auto brightness "ON" in my device settings and the brightness level is about 30% in the slider.

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Have you tried if 7.1 has improved?

Comment: Yes I tried 7.1, same problem exists as in 7.0.